# How to forcefully close GetX Snackbar?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx, snackbar

I am using `Get.snackbar()` to show the process of connection to API.
I don't understand how programmatically close a snackbar?
I have the following code:

```
@override
  Future<List> getImportantData(String inputData) async {
    try {
      final token =  basicApiAuthString;
      print("requesting API with the following request: $inputData");
      Get.snackbar(
          "Requesting very important data...",
          "",
          duration: 60.seconds, // it could be any reasonable time, but I set it lo-o-ong
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          showProgressIndicator: true,
          isDismissible: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
          colorText: Colors.white,
        );
      List importantData = await _client.requestAPI(basicAuthString: token, body: inputData);
          .then((importantData) {
              // Here I need to dismiss the snackbar I am still showing to user
              print("I want to close snackbar here but I don't know how to do that!");
              // Then I return data for future processing... 
              return importantData;
                });

      return importantData;
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      // Here I handle all possible API errors... Also I want to close snackbar here as well.
  
    }
 } // getImportantData() function.
```

I need to take into account, the following:

1. app may be closed and open again during the request (so the snackbar may be closed, but I can know it by status callback (not shown)
2. The snackbar may be dismissed by the user during request
3. request may be completed in milliseconds
4. There are possible API errors and `.then()` portion will never be executed.

So, I need some external way to close the snack. `Navigator.of(context).hide...` is not the solution as I use GetX.

—————
PS: Here is the definition of snackbar that doesn't help me to clarify:

https://pub.dev/documentation/get/3.4.2/route_manager/GetNavigation/snackbar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use Get.back() to close the snack bar.
```

If you want the user to close snack bar, You can use `Get.back` either in mainButton or onTap

```
   Get.snackbar(
      "Requesting very important data...",
      "",
      duration: 60.seconds, // it could be any reasonable time, but I set it lo-o-ong
      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      showProgressIndicator: true,
      isDismissible: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      colorText: Colors.white,
      mainButton: TextButton(
            onPressed: Get.back,
            child: const Text(
              "Close"
      )));
   );
```

If debugLocked issue arise on close, use SchedulerBinding

```
 SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Your Get Snackbar
 }):
```

Comment: Also try `Get.back(closeOverlays: true);`

Comment: I only tried solution Get.back(closeOverlays: true); from @rajagopalx and it works thank you so much

Comment: I show both Get.dialog and Get.snackbar . But sometimes only Get.dialog. how to close properly

Answer (score 12):

GetX has already a method called `closeAllSnackbars()` and `closeCurrentSnackbar()`.

So use `closeAllSnackbars()` to close all open Snackbars.

```
Get.closeAllSnackbars();
```

And to close the current active snakbar simply call `closeCurrentSnackbar()`.

```
Get.closeCurrentSnackbar();
```

You can also check weather the snackbar is open/active or not by calling `isSnackbarOpen()` .

```
Get.isSnackbarOpen();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've another approach where you can assign the snackbar to **SnackbarController**, and then you can close the **Snackbar** using `SnackbarController.close`.
This is a special use case, and if you have more than one snackbar then you can assign the specific snackbar (which you want to close) to the **SnackbarController** and then you can close it.
Here is an example:

```
    SnackbarConteroller? snackController;
    snackController = Get.snackbar(
              "Title",
               "Hello everyone");
    snackController?.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to close the current Snackbar immediately

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
```

Comment: Hmm...
tried the following to no avail:
`final X = Get.context;` and 
              `ScaffoldMessenger.of(X!).removeCurrentSnackBar();`
Looks like in the GetX environment there is another way should be used.

Comment: you have to pass the build context not the "Get.context"